# use of issuance as noun

Tags: word-usage

My question is that can we use issuance as a noun. I could not find issuance in Oxford Advanced  Learner's Dictionary. Even then, use of this word is common in Indian sub-continent.Especially when writing a letter or an application.
For example: 
Sub: Issuance of certificate or issuance of N.O.C.

Is writing "issue of Certificate" correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It'sa probably not in your *learner's* dictionary because it's such an uncommon word you're not likely to need it unless your English is so good you'd automatically know how to derive it from the base form and use/understand it anyway. The full (subscription-only) OED has an entry defining **issuance** - *the action of issuing or granting something.*

Comment: If a word is listed in a dictionary, you can be almost sure that it exists, but the opposite is not true: a word not being in a dictionary (and especially a learner's dictionary) is not evidence that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Issuance is often used for shares: the issuance of shares. For a certificate, the issuing of a certificate. issue of certificate is not right. Words are  used in context and a dictionary does not always give context as required. The function can be: issuance of certificates. Issuance of certificates is limited to this agency. As a reference in a letter, it would depend on what the intended meaning is: Issuance of certificates is fine.

Comment: I agree with J. Siebeneichler that a word not being in a dictionary is not evidence that it doesn't exist. The mentioned dictionary was not the only one which I consulted. Anyway, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MOHD HAMZA Dictionaries do not always provide usage. Usage is provided by those who have interiorized the language and culture, and, it is hoped, know what standard writing forms are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Issuance* [appears valid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issuance) since early to mid-19th Century, at least [in American English](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=issuance).

Writing "issue of Certificate" is correct; see the following definition from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issue):

a :  *the act of publishing or officially giving out or making available*

The meaning of *issuance*
  relates so closely to a subset of the definition of *issue* as to be interchangeable in many circumstances.

Comment: That "official publication" sense is just one possible *metaphoric* usage. Obviously the word can also be used literally, as in [*liquid issuance*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22liquid+issuance%22) (from a leaky pipe, say).

Comment: Yes, agreed. Not sure if you mean this point indicates a deficiency in my answer though. Please let me know if so.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say my point indicates a *deficiency* in your answer, no. After all, your final sentence points out that ***issuance*** is potentially interchangeable with ***issue*** in many circumstances ([*a sperm reservoir from which there was a slow **issue** of actively vital spermatozoa*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+slow+issue+of+actively+vital+spermatozoa%22), for example). I admit I haven't actually upvoted you, but that's really because I don't think much of the question in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the "issue of certificate" is most definitely not correct. /The issuing of a certificate is what is required./ or /Issuing certificates is the role of this agency/ But not: the issue of certificate. The OP's context is pretty clear. It is  not some abstruse thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why keep repeating the thing about spermatozoa? That is simply not the context here. Ergo, it is not relevant. In any case, a slow issue has nothing to do with the noun as asked about here. You can issue certificates but the ***activity*** is not: issue of certificates. To issue as a verb is basically to stream out or come out (slowly).

Comment: @Lambie, I'm confused about your statement that "issue" cannot be used correctly in "issue of certificate". Are you saying that this usage is wrong in itself? Or is there something about the context that makes it wrong just in this instance?

Comment: One more thing is needed to be cleared. Issue is also noun, so why it should not be used instead of issuance.

Comment: @Lambie: Repeating? I posted *one* link to *one* written instance of a context where ***issue*** could be replaced by ***issuance*** (as, for example, [*one can get a slow **issuance** of drops of a uniform size*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+slow+issuance+of+drops%22)). The question happens to ask about the validity of ***metaphoric*** "issuance" (referring to bits of paper being distributed, rather than fluids leaking), but it makes more sense to address the general case. Btw - I think your distinction between noun "issue" and gerund "issuing" is just plain nonsensical.

Comment: If you are talking about certificates and an agency or authority or institution that **puts them out** (issues them), you have to say: the issuing of certificates or the issuance of certificate. If  you say: the issue of certificates in that sense, it is ***wrong***. Is that clear enough?? ***You would never say***: The issue of certificates takes place on Mondays. You would say: Certificates are issued on Mondays/The issuing of certificates is on Mondays. [somewhat awkward]/Certificate issuance is on Monday. Is that clear??

Comment: @MOHD HAMZA Issue is also a noun, with a different meaning. Merriam Webster:  the act of publishing or officially giving out or making available: the next issue of commemorative stamps// issue of supplies by the quartermaster// But NOT therefore, the issue of certificates!!! Certificates are not **published**, **officially given out or made available** **like supplies or stamps**. They are issued TO a person, yes.

Comment: Hi @Lambie, thanks for the reply. If I'm understanding correctly, your concern may be with the lack of an article for "certificate" in the example, i.e. that "the issue of certificate" is wrong, but "the issue of **a** certificate", (or "issuing of certificates") is correct.
Neither the OP nor my answer used the form "the issue of certificate". I used "issue of certificate" per the question. I had in mind the abbreviated style of headlines, titles, instructions, etc. For example, a field on a form might read "Date of **issue of certificate**:"
Please correct me if I've still misunderstood.

Comment: @remant, I've answered the question. The form should say: ***issue date of certificate***. The OP did not give enough context. Date of issue of certificate is not really correct. "The issue of a certificate" is wrong, unless it means the problem. I'm done here.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks for your explanation.  Here I would like to repeat your explanation that was very helpful: "if you are talking about certificates and an agency or authority or institution that puts them out (issues them), you have to say: the issuing of certificates or the issuance of certificate. If you say: the issue of certificates in that sense, it is wrong. Is that clear enough?? You would never say: The issue of certificates takes place on Mondays. You would say: Certificates are issued on Mondays/The issuing of certificates is on Mondays. [somewhat awkward]/Certificate issuance is on...

Comment: I am also thankful to all who shared their knowledge with mew here.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to legal usage, one would say: issuance of certificates. This is usually how it is stated in laws and in legal documents:

American English - 49 U.S. Code § 44702 - Issuance of certificates

British English - 2.2. An “Interim certificate” is a certificate issued by the attending surveyor upon satisfactory completion of a survey in order to permit the ship to trade while the permanent/full term certificate is prepared. An interim certificate is usually valid for five months from the date of
issuance.
http://www.iacs.org.uk/document/public/Publications/Resolution_changes/PDF/REC_098_Rev1_pdf1793.pdf  [issuance](http://www.iacs.org.uk/document/public/Publications/Resolution_changes/PDF/REC_098_Rev1_pdf1793.pdf)

Australian English - [issuance of certificates](http://learn.nps.org.au/mod/page/view.php?id=4444)
Indian English - [issuance of certificates](http://www.akgec.in/index.php/academics/issuance-of-certificates)
Caribbean (Jamaican) English - [issuance of certificates](http://www.fspid.gov.jm/national-food-comp-prog.html)

And on and on and on.

[issuance of certificates](http://www.iacs.org.uk/document/public/Publications/Resolution_changes/PDF/REC_098_Rev1_pdf1793.pdf)https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/49/44702

Issuance is the formal function of issuing certificates. "issue of certificate" is simply not standard.

Grammar: 
- The issuing of certificates will take place during the week.
- Certificates will be issued during the week.
- There is no certificate issuance on Mondays.

These are just examples of usage.

I only gave two examples and avoided the dictionary but the it can now be googled as: issuance of certificates and the OP will see how standard it is in all varieties of English. What is important here is not the dictionary but **in-context usage**. A dictionary will not show how often this is used. It is everywhere in the English-speaking world.